# What is the best way to maintain single props value across the application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing a multi-tenant application using MVC. Once I launch my application in browser I find the `TenantId` and assign in to `static` property to maintain across the application like

```
 public static int TenantId
 {
     get { return _tenantId; }
     set
     {
         _tenantId = value;
         string path = HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath;

         TenantConfigurationModel tenantConfiguration = HospitalFacade.GetTenantIdByUrl(path);
         if (tenantConfiguration != null)
         {                   
             _tenantId = tenantConfiguration.TenantId;
         }                              
     }
}
```

But my co developers suggest **session**

What is the best way to maintain single props value across the application?

**Is any advantages/disadvantage using static property ?**

Comment: If it's static, it'll be shared by *every* user. If that's what you want, go for it.

Comment: @AntP It shared to all users

Comment: So all users are supposed to see the same TenantId? Sounds a bit off to me.

Comment: This is not a user based application all anonymous user also access my application. Whenever anonymous  user access my application it based upon my URL get TenantId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sessions: Sessions are for a specific user. Which means that if 2 users visit your website then both of them will have different sessions. Each session will have its own values related to the users.

So in nutshell, if the value that you are trying to make available in the whole application is user dependent then use sessions.

Check the answer on an other question: [Static fields vs Session variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14723486/static-fields-vs-session-variables)

No, using static variables for this is not the way to go:

1. If your AppDomain is recycled, all your static variables will be
   "reset"
2. Static variables don't scale horizontally - if you load-balance your application, a user who hits one server then a different one won't see the data sotre in the static variables in the first server
3. Most importantly, static variables will be shared by all access to that server... it won't be on a per-user basis at all... whereas from your description, you wouldn't want user X to see user Y's information.

Comment: Sessions can be maintained in MVC by three ways: tempdata, viewdata, and viewbag.

Comment: @AbiRuban `TempData`/`ViewData` and `ViewBag` are not synonymous with `Session`.

Comment: But i don't want store the value to user specific

Comment: @AbiRuban That's fine but with your current implementation if the static variables are reset (which *will* happen) then they will start returning default values. What you should have is a custom *get* accessor that validates the static backing field and then fetches it again if it's invalid. If you can't do this, you get it from some persistent source every time as per James' answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are *many* disadvantages of using a `static` property and not that many advantages (from a web application perspective).

Your question is a little confusing, you say it's a multi-tenant site yet you want to share the tenancy ID across *all* the users. Regardless, if the goal is to share data across *every* possible user on the site then consider just storing the value in a database or, if speed is a concern, some persistent caching solution like [Redis](http://redis.io/).