# Replace static classes / fields in C# MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, oop

A User who logs in to the system using functions in the Users class.
now i need to read the User's fields (UserID, FullName, GroupID...) from other classes and this seems to me a bit complicated...
i cannot use static variables in the users class because they will stay in the memory till the appdomain is recycled and of course i cannot instantiate a new user object because i need the info that have been already instantiated.

how can i retrieve the Users fields / properties from other class?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to store something that references the logged-in user, for example their UserID, within the [ViewData or TempData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993263/viewbag-viewdata-and-tempdata).  This will allow you to retrieve their info from your database based on their UserID.

Then in the classes that need to read this user's data, you will instantiate a User object (whatever you have named it) and populate the object's properties with data from the database for this user.

Comment: Well yes exactly! but the thing is that i was trying to reduce the amount of database connections and so i thought to save all those info in the classes attributes

Comment: besides everytime that i need to get the user info i have to instantiate a Users class. Static could be a perfect solution if it serves only the unique request

Comment: In that case, if this is just temporary, you could look at storing a Dictionary<UserID,User> or as your own generic data structure in ViewData, but it will eat up your server's memory if you have a large number of users being stored here at once.  Honestly, unless you just have very poor performance with your network or DB server, you may be straying into micro-optimization here - just a fair warning.

Comment: yes you're right! i also found other threads recommending almost the same solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14723486/static-fields-vs-session-variables